# Forfiles - sorting files

Tags: cmd

I need to write simple script. The point is to sort the files in a folder whose name is the first letter of file name. I understand sequence of actions (get first letter of `@fname`; check if folder exist; create folder; move file) but i don't understand how it all write without block of code(`do` and `end`). Does forfiles blocks `do/end`? Or how I can write this script without block?

Comment: Give an example of what you need to sort.  `Forfiles` may not be the best tool.

Comment: @foxidrive File `test.txt` move to folder `t`, file `example.exe` to folder named `e` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another method:

```
@echo off
   for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
      if exist "%%a*" md "%%a" 2>nul & move "%%a*" "%%a"
   )
pause
```

Comment: yes, but he wants a solution without `(` blocks `)`.

Comment: @stephen I think OP can't integrate them into Forfiles.  That was an `or` question, but the OP will have to return to confirm or deny. :D

Comment: reading the question some times more, you may be right. Anyway, the two solutions shows clearly how powerful those blocks are.

Comment: Thanks. I used a similar method. But instead of the set of numbers and letters I user `(*)` and then used block `do ()`. I originally wanted to use `forfiles` (He seemed easier) But then I figured out the `for` and did it all with him. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

dir /b /a-d *.* >tmp
echo END OF FILE>>tmp
echo -- start --

:loop
set /p file=<tmp
if "%file%"=="END OF FILE" goto :end
if "%file%"=="tmp" goto :ignore

md %file:~0,1%\%file% 2>nul
move "%file%" "%file:~0,1%\%file%"

:ignore
more +1 tmp >tmp2
del tmp
ren tmp2 tmp
goto :loop

:end
echo -- finish --
exit /b
```

Puh - I'm starting to love those blocks ^^

No need to check if the folder already exist, `md`will make it when it doesn't exist and give an error if it does exist (`2>nul` sends it to nirvana)